# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Cannot find JAR 'bndlib-2.4.0.jar' required by module 'gradle-osgi' using classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-virtual-device

I am new to android studio 2.1.2, the following error is occurring while running the app in `Genymotion AVD`.

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
  Cannot find JAR 'bndlib-2.4.0.jar' required by module 'gradle-osgi' using classpath or distribution directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10'.
```

Please help me on this bug.

Comment: It seems like you don't have "bndlib-2.4.0.jar". Just copy it and paste it in libs folder, then clean & rebuild app. and run

Comment: Thank you Onkar Nene. It worked. I just did the same as you told and it's working.